# Static sound in cordless phone connected to internet dsl

Tags: phone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static sound in cordless phone connected to internet dsl](https://superuser.com/questions/188261/static-sound-in-cordless-phone-connected-to-internet-dsl)

I live in Orange County Southern California USA.

I get internet dsl/phone connection (not land line) from AT&T.

A single phone wire comes out of the phone jack and connects to AT&T modem. AT&T modem connects to Linksys router. Link Sys router connects to Lingo box. Lingo box connects to my wireless phone panasonic.

With this arrangement, I get lot of static on my phone. I have also tried connecting filter to my phone jack but phone static does not go away.

Any time, i call AT&T, Lingo, Linksys they tell me that their systems are fine contact the other vendor to solve my phone static problem.

I am very frustrated !!

Please help.

Comment: Dupe ?  [Static sound in cordless phone connected to internet dsl](http://superuser.com/questions/188261/static-sound-in-cordless-phone-connected-to-internet-dsl)

Comment: not a dupe, this is voip.

Answer (score 0):

Why a filter? that will just make your dsl go awry and will have no affect on a voip phone
Have you tried with a wired phone? is there still static?
Any time you troubleshoot, simplify. Remove all but the lingo box and use a wired phone. Is there still static?
Have you swapped out any of your cables?

Comment: Also, is it a 2.4Ghz phone and there's wifi in use nearby?